# How to use ChromeDriver in Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get it to run multiple tests with the @test, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work. I found this example from 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ 
Here is my code:

```
package com.chrometester.webdriver;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.openqa.jetty.util.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ChromeTest extends TestCase {

    private static ChromeDriverService service;
    private WebDriver driver;



    @Before
    public void createDriver() {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),
                DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoogleSearch() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // rest of the test...
    }


    @After
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: Error:(17, 12) java: constructor TestCase in class org.openqa.jetty.util.TestCase cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: where exactly the exception is coming from and I guess you have imported the wrong package for Testcase

Comment: Intellij tells me that there is no default constructor available in "org.openqa.jetty.util.TestCase"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are using the @Test annotation from TestNG instead of Junit. Change the import, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

junit.framework.TestCase
Testcase import I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to use TestNG instead of Junit. Here example

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Settings {
protected static WebDriver driver;
protected static String baseURL = "your base url";
public static ChromeDriverService service;
@BeforeClass
public static void createAndStartService() {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("pass to your chrome")).usingAnyFreePort()
            .withSilent(true)
            .withVerbose(false)
            .build();
    try {
        service.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@AfterClass
public static void createAndStopService() {
    service.stop();
}
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    driver.get(baseURL);
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}

public static WebDriver getDriver()
{
    return driver;
}
```

And your class with test will be look like

```
public class Tests extends Settings {
    @Test(groups = "smoke tests registration", description = "example")
    public void test_base_url() {
        driver.get(baseURL);
    }
```